# find primes number starting at 2 Haskell

Tags: haskell

Write a function called isPrime that determines if an Integer is a prime number (evenly
divisible only by itself and one). For reference, here’s a list of the primes less than 100:
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
What are the 1000th through 1020th prime numbers? (starting at 2)

```
isPrime :: [Integer] 
isPrime = sieve [2..1020]
  where
    sieve (p:xs)
    | p*p <= 1020 = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0] 
    | otherwise = (p:xs)
```

I tried this code, but it prints primes 2 through 1020.
I want to show 1000 through 1020 starting at 2

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating primes up to 1020, to emit the 1000th through 1020th primes, you can generate the first 1020 primes and emit only the last 21 of them.

Using [a naive unbounded sieve](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), we can write the following

```
minus :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
minus (x:xs) (y:ys) = case (compare x y) of
           LT -> x : minus  xs  (y:ys)
           EQ ->     minus  xs     ys
           GT ->     minus (x:xs)  ys
minus  xs     _     = xs

primes :: [Integer]
primes = eratos [2..]
  where
    eratos []     = []
    eratos (p:xs) = p : eratos (xs `minus` [p, p+p..])

primesFromTo from to = drop (from-1) $ take to primes
```

Then find `primesFromTo 1000 1020`:

```
*Main> primesFromTo 1000 1020
[7919,7927,7933,7937,7949,7951,7963,7993,8009,8011,8017,8039,8053,8059,8069,8081,8087,8089,8093,8101,8111]
```

As an aside, the naming (`isPrimes`) is a bit questionable for a list of primes...